# Truth-teller problem

Tags: logic

In a town N, every person is either a truth-teller, who always tells the truth, or a liar, who always lies. Every person in town $N$ took part in a survey. "Is winter your favorite season?" was answered "yes" by $40\%$ of respondents. A similar question about spring had $30\%$ of affirmative answers, about summer had $50\%$, and about autumn had $0\%$. What percent of the town's population actually has winter as a favorite season? The answer is __ $\% $.

I saw 2 variants of solution the problem:

1. $40\% / (40\% + 30\% + 50\%) = 33.3\%$
2. $40\% - (40\% + 30\% + 50\% - 100\%) = 20\%$

Can someone help with solution? The second solution based on the theory that every person is truth-teller (because if everyone is a liar, the autumn is the only answer). So, the total percentage of answers is $40\% + 30\% + 50\% = 120\%$. The overlap of 20% should be deducted from winter (?) answer and we got $20\%$ as an answer.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts (and to edit out the duplicated text).  As a way to get started:  figure out the percentage of liars.

Comment: Note: the argument you describe for the second solution is hard to follow.  I assume we are to imagine that each citizen has a unique favorite season (else the problem can't be answered).  But in that case it is not possible that everyone is honest, since the percents add over $100$, so some people are saying Yes to more than one season.

Comment: So, the percentage of liars should be the sum of answers minus 100% = 20%?

Comment: Why should that be true?  Just work it out.  Assume $x\%$ are Liars, soo $100-x\%$ are Truth Tellers.  Under that assumption, how many Yes votes would you get?  Use that to solve for $x$.